# How to set server.mapath for pdf creation?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I am generting pdf documents using itextsharp. I have set a `string path`. program works properly but the pdf file saves in my project folder. I want to set this path to my system `F` disk. My current code is

```
 string path = Server.MapPath("Reports");
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path +""+name+".pdf", FileMode.Create));
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path + "name.pdf");
```

How can I Set `string path = Server.MapPath("Reports");` to my system F disk. I applied strait path like

```
string path = Server.MapPath(@"F:\reports\");
```

but it shows error like its not a virtual path..How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `MapPath` does is turn a relative path in your IIS project to the absolute path the IIS project is deployed to. If you want to use the fixed path just enter a fixed path

```
string path = @"F:\reports\";
```

You could also add it to [the application settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your `web.config` and read the path from there.

```
//In your code
var path = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["savePath"];
```

```
<!-- in web.config -->
<appSettings>
  <add key="savePath" value="F:\reports\"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Oh..Thank you.I were not aware about this.